# Need to transpose a time series in Excel into a format readable by Stata

Tags: excel, vba, stata

The format of the data is this.

```
Obs1 Var1 var1ObsPeriod1 var1obsPeriod2
Obs1 var2 var2ObsPeriod1 var2obsPeriod2
..
Obs2 var96 var96obs
...
```

and so on.

I need to transform this into

```
obs              var1              var2        var96
obs1            var1obs           var2obs... var96obs
obs1Period2     var1obsPer2       var2obsPer2 ....
obs2            var1obs....
```

It's a fairly simple operation in C# (the only language I know decently); however I'm unable to figure out how to do it with the tools accorded (Excel/VBA).

Can anybody help with this? It's a fairly simple operation in C#, where all I would need to do is apply a couple of loops and transform this into a 2d array with a row for each obs and its specific time period. However, I do not know how to do this in excel/vba.

I get that this is a big task, but can anybody point me towards how to set this up? (Can I use a 2d string or is there an equivalent...and so on.)

Img link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD5Cd.jpg
Here's a more concrete example of what I need: the part at the top is how the data currently is; the part at the bottom is what I need it to become.

[image]

Comment: The layout of the data -- neither what you have nor what you want -- isn't at all clear from your abstract example. Please provide better layout and/or a concrete example.

Comment: Modified and corrected it. I hadn't applied the code tag properly to the original post.

Comment: Sorry, it's improved but I still don't understand it. I think you still need a concrete example.  Any way, if the aim is to import into Stata, can you be sure that you won't be better off reshaping in Stata?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it in stata. I'm pretty sure it can be done in VBA (all I need to transform it are a couple of loops and a 2d string), so I'm looking at VBA tuts for Excel right now.

Comment: http://imgur.com/teXdo9x Here's a more concrete example of what I need: the part at the top is how the data currently is; the part at the bottom is what I need it to become.

Comment: How to deal with that data structure in Stata is documented at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0031

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your initial data in Stata (see `help import`), then one way is:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
obs str1 vartitle period1 period2
1         "x"         25       45
1         "y"         67       89
2         "x"         56       23
2         "y"         98       34
end

order vartitle obs
sort vartitle obs

list

*----- what you want -----

// stack
stack period1 obs vartitle period2 obs vartitle, ///
    into(metric obs2 vartitle2) clear

isid vartitle2 obs2 _stack, sort
rename _stack period

// reshape
by vartitle2: gen obs = _n
reshape wide metric, i(obs) j(vartitle2) string
rename metric* *

// clean
order obs obs2 period
list
```

The variable `obs` can be thought of as a unique identifier for each observation. `obs2` can be thought of as a panel identifier.

Key are `help stack` and `help reshape`. Use `list` to check what's going on with the database in between commands.

Comment: Thank you. I've figured it out through VBA in excel(it was actually as simple a transformation as I thought it was), but knowing what you just pointed out will help me in my subsequent work in stata. So, thanks.